# Inserir dois pontos na string

Tags: php, string

Eu tenho a seguinte *string*:

```
$valor = "0050";
```

Como eu faço para inserir dois pontos depois da segunda casa e ficar desta forma?

```
00:50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o que você tem é

```
$valor = "0050";
```

é só fazer assim:

```
$valor = "00:50";
```

Se o que você tem é uma variável que tem 4 caracteres desconhecidos e quer separá-los é só fazer

```
$valor = substr($valor, 0, 2) . ":" . substr($valor, 2);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Format.php).

Se não sabe bem o critério aí fica complicado resolver, precisaria decidir uma regra.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de resolver esse problema é utilizar a função [substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php). O que faz ela funcionar da maneira desejada é informar o quarto argumento como zero. Assim será adicionado o caracter na posição definida no terceiro argumento (nesse exemplo a dois)

```
$valor = '0099';
echo substr_replace($valor, ':', 2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderá utilizar a função `strtotime` do php, formatando a hora conforme sua necessidade:

```
$valor = "0050";

$time = date("H:i", strtotime($valor));

echo $time;
```

O resultado será uma string de valor 00:50.